# Desabilitar input text ao clicar em outro input text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa Tarde,

Tenho os dois inputs abaixo:

```
<input type="text" id="txtEntrada" name="entrada" onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);" >     
<input type="text" id="txtSaida" name="saida" onkeyup="somenteNumeros(this);">
```

Gostaria que ao clicar no input Entrada o Saída fosse desabilitado e vice-versa.
Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $("#txtEntrada").blur(function(){  
    if ($("#txtEntrada").val() !=''){
      $('#txtSaida').attr("disabled", true);
    }else{
      $('#txtSaida').attr("disabled", false);
    }
  });   
});
</script>
```

Algum com uma sugestão melhor?

Comment: Bia, se por exemplo eu clicar inicialmente no `txtEntrada` então o `txtSaida`ficará desabilitado e não será possível clicar nele novamente, é esse comportamento que você espera?

Comment: Do jeito que você tá colocando parece que eles são excludentes, é isso? Se eu preencher `txtSaida` eu não posso preencher `txtEntrada`?

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior esse é meu dilema, gostaria que fosse possível sim clicar no **txtSaida** novamente.

Comment: Sim @EduardoAlmeida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você precisa que quando clicar em um input o outro desabilite certo? Então fiz um script usando apenas JavaScript.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  
  var self = e.target;
  
  if(['entrada','saida'].indexOf(self.id) !== -1) {
    var el = document.getElementById(self.id === 'entrada' ? 'saida' : 'entrada');
    
    self.removeAttribute('disabled');
    
    el.setAttribute('disabled','');
    el.value = "";
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="entrada" name="entrada">     
<input type="text" id="saida" name="saida">
```

Comment: É exatamente isso, obrigada.

Comment: vanilla js o rei dos frameworks! uha

Comment: Dúvida @devgaspa, esse trecho:

`if(['txtEntrada','txtSaida'].indexOf(self.id) !== -1)`

faz oque?

Comment: @Bia este trecho do código verifica se o valor do atributo `id` de `self`(elemento clicado) é um dos dois valores declarados no array `['txtEntrada','txtSaida']`, ele faz essa verificação usando o `indexOf`, se o valor de `id` não existir no array a função  retornará `-1`. Usei este método para validar os elementos clicados por que estou atribuindo o evento `click` ao documento, se fosse somente aos itens não seria necessário está validação. Leia sobre **indexOf** [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Muito obrigada @devgaspa

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer exatamente o que você pediu basta adicionar o atributo `disabled` ao `txt` no momento em que clica no outro. Porém isso fica meio estranho, pois no momento que selecionar um txt não poderei mais selecionar o outro. Veja o exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $txtEntrada = $("#txtEntrada");
  var $txtSaida = $("#txtSaida");

  $txtEntrada.on('click', function() {
    $txtSaida.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });

  $txtSaida.on('click', function() {
    $txtEntrada.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtEntrada" name="entrada">
<input type="text" id="txtSaida" name="saida">
```

Comment: Seu código não funcionou aqui, estou usando o Chrome v46.

Comment: Também estou no Chrome @devgaspa e está funcionando aqui. O que não fiz nesse código é permitir que o txt que foi desabilitado seja habilitado novamente como você fez na tua resposta.

Comment: Você está apenas desabilitando os campos. Quando for desabilitar tem que verificar se o clicado está desabilitado e habilita-lo.

Comment: @devgaspa tentei fazer isso, porém não sei porque o evento `click` não é chamado quando clico no txt desabilitado. To tentando achar o motivo

Comment: Essa pergunta pode te ajudar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/event-on-a-disabled-input

Comment: Pois é, pra fazer isso sem `POG` só com `JavaScript` puro como você fez.

Answer (score 0):

Eu vou deixar esse código aqui, caso alguém queira utilizar:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#txtEntrada, #txtSaida').keyup(function(){
    if($('#txtEntrada').val().length > 0){
      $('#txtSaida').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    else if($('#txtSaida').val().length > 0){
      $('#txtEntrada').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    else{
      $('#txtEntrada, #txtSaida').attr('disabled', false);
    }
  });
})
```

Basicamente, eu desabilito os inputs quando o outro tem algum valor e não simplesmente quando eu seleciono, porque assim, se eu errar o preenchimento, conseguirei deletar os dados de um input e passar para o outro sem problemas.